# Memory allocation of a Class auto properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I have a class with multiple properties. For example

```
public class Customer
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string abc{ get; set; }
        public bool abcd { get; set; }
        public string abcde { get; set; }
        public string abcdef { get; set; }
        public string abcdefg { get; set; }
        public string abcdefgh { get; set; }
        public string xyz { get; set; }     
    }
```

Now I want to know how much memory space is consumed by the get set properties.
I only require few of the properties in one of my API call and all of these properties for another API call.
So I want to know whether I should create two different classes and use them for my separate API calls or just use one common class with multiple get set properties and use it for my API calls.
Any guidance will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: For `int` and `bool` the memory usage is negligible but `string` can vary as it's not a value type (string length makes up most of the `String` size).

Comment: Why not create one class with the minimum properties for one API and extend the class for the other?

Comment: as @SombreroChicken said - this heavily depends on the length of strings, but generally should be negligible.

Comment: As I was going through similar questions over so , I observed that get set are methods and they do not consume memory unless specifically binded from back end.

Comment: " Straight from Apress Illustrated C#

Unlike a field, however, a property is a function member.
- It does not allocate memory for data storage! " its one of the comment I saw on one of similar SO questions. But I do not know the definite answer to this

Comment: @SC-ML-SP an automatically implemented property is *implemented* as a field and one or more accessor methods; only the field has a cost per object, and that cost is: the size of the type being stored

Comment: " and they do not consume memory unless specifically binded from back end." - if I understand the sentence correctly: then that is simply not how automatically implemented properties work. A **property accessor** is a method, sure; but the data has to be stored somewhere, and that somewhere is - in the case of an automatically implemented property - a field. I think what that author is trying to say is that *the accessor itself* - i.e. having a property rather than a naked field - doesn't require *additional* storage

Answer (score 1):

the `int` and `bool` will typically be packed together into 8 bytes; the `string` references take 4 (32-bit) or 8 (64-bits) for the references. If the strings *have non-null values*, then that space will be allocated separately and will be whatever the string needs.

But frankly: unless you're allocating *millions* of them, splitting it into 2 different types **won't save you anything real** - it will just be yak shaving. Especially for the scenario where the strings are `null`.

Comment: I do like me some yaks

Comment: @Marc Yes, thanks for the explanation. Well, the scenario is when I am making a call, that call requires three of the properties of my class. but when I am using another call (Both calls in same cs file) I am sending and setting data to all of properties. So I want to be clear regarding the first call as its sending null to the api and its getting null in the response for unused fields. So I want to know about memory overheads in my scenario

Comment: @SC-ML-SP the number of fields here is the same regardless of what members you touch in any particular code path; but: you *seriously seriously* don't need to worry about that - allocating an object with a few fields that aren't used *isn't a problem* at all. The only time that *could ever* be a problem is when you're allocating *vast* numbers of objects that live longer than GEN0/GEN1, but in that case: it isn't the *fields* that is the real problem - but rather: *the vast number of objects*

Comment: Yes I want to use one common class for all my customer related queries, but my fellow developer insisting me to use two classes. One he created with the properties he requires. and another class that I created with all the needed properties. As I am told that when he will use my class with several properties and send it to Api (null in unused properties) then it will create a memory overhead. So I need a clear picture of what should be the best in terms of memory usage.

Comment: @SC-ML-SP that's *almost certainly not* a real problem; I *can* respect limiting the API to what you need *simply to keep it clean*, but memory allocation isn't the issue here

Answer (score 0):

We have to exclude the string. This one can be anywhere from "null" to "whatever Max Lenght for string was today".

Theoretically a Autoimplement Property should cost as much as a minimal, manual property: One backing field. One get and one set function for the entire type. The single most important rule about properties is to not accidentally access the backing field in class code. And Autoimplement Properties do that, by simply not giving the Backing Field a name you could use. It is still there. It propably has a name derived from the Property name for Reflection. But your code has no realy way to access it.

Theoreitically, because now coems in the JiT. The JiT can do a lot of Optimisations:

- Those Automatic accessors are very little code. So there is a decent chance that the cost of [Inlining them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) is below the cost of calling them. So I give it a 90% chance the JiT will inline those.
- If you create a temporary variable to use it the next line, this one might run into DeadCode detection. Wich means it will be cut out and replaced by the originall access.
- But of coruse it goes the other way too. In order to get around the overhead inherent in ArrayBounds Checks, the JiT might detect "redundant Acesses" with teh same Index and create a temporary variable to use.

While I have not read about it yet, I would not rule out that the JiT can even cut unused properties from classes. It is all just runtime optimisations. It at least can cut unaccessed varriables (and their initialsiation) out as dead code. As I found out when I tried forcing a 2 GiB OOM:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace OOM_32_forced
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //each short is 2 byte big, Int32.MaxValue is 2^31.
            //So this will require a bit above 2^32 byte, or 2 GiB
            short[] Array = new short[Int32.MaxValue];

            /*need to actually access that array
            Otherwise JIT compiler and optimisations will just skip
            the array definition and creation */
            foreach (short value in Array)
                Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

I agree that this is Micro Optimisations. But even more, those might be ones the JiT can do for you *already*. So you might save nothing at all. Personally I prefer read- and debugability of code way before such Optimisations. I can often do something "ineffective" because I can rest in the knowledge the JiT will propably deal with it.